# Output every javascript code line that was executed and/or execute code step by step no matter in what "process", timer e.t.c. the code is executed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

Is there a way to output every javascript code line that was executed and/or execute code step by step no matter in what "process", timer e.t.c. the code is executed?

My idea is that because Google Chrome browser "knows" which javascript code it executes, there has to be a way to at least output each line of code that is being executed(), line by line.
The project is not straightforward and I just want to see after which line thing that I'm investigating is happening.

Any suggestions, may be some Addon? Thanks.

P.S. I can open "Developer Tools", go to "Profiles", click "Start", do what I want as a user in web-browser, then click "Stop" and then see which functions were executed. But they are not in the order of execution.

Comment: Use chromes built in debugger.

Comment: I'm using it, but it doesn't do what I want, please read the question.

Comment: You are using the Profiler, the debugger is located under the Sources tab. [*(screenshot)*](http://i.imgur.com/0NTfpGB.png)

Comment: C5H8NNaO4, I know where the debug is and I often use it, but it doesn't do what I want it to do: at least output every line that was executed without me setting breakpoints in every function that is working by timer and manually executing code step-by-step.

Comment: Why would you want to output every executed statement? Are you interested in which fucntions get called ? you could use the [commandLineAPIs](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api) `monitor` function

Comment: I want to output every executed statement because I want to quickly scroll through this output list of code lines and see in which order they were executed. I know it will be enormous, I'm ok with that. And I see no reason why Google Chrome can't do that(Except may be nobody needs this feature, except me, apparently).
I don't want to manually go through the code step-by-step or use "console.log('')" in many places.

The commandLineAPIs is very interesting, thank you very much for that link, I've never used it. And "monitor" function seems pretty helpful for me, thanks.

Comment: @JoeSmith Did you ever find a solution? I'm looking for the offending function for my question http://stackoverflow.com/q/31747969/8681 and I think having a tool to see what function is executing (too) often would help me a lot!

Comment: @Jorn, no I didn't find a solution to this. Guess writing "console.log("<function name>)" at the start of functions of interest are the closest thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the Debugger: you can set breakpoints inline your javascript source code and when browser read the instruction where you put that breakpoint, the browser stop execution. Then you can watch step by step what's happening and the changes of variables just press a button through you can execute next function. Just press mouse right button on your page and select 'Inspect element'>'Sources'

Comment: I know about that, thank you.
The thing is in this project there are very many things that are happening in different "processses", let's say a lot of things are happening inside "setIntervals". It's not that clear what's going on when I just set breakpoint and execute it step by step. I would rather see whole logs of what happened or somehow execute code step by step, but despite of where the code is.

Comment: I think you should use a most powerful debugger tool. Take a look to 'Firebug', and extension for Firefox. I think it can help you.

Comment: The project was written mainly for Chrome and IEs, so it's not fully functional in Firefox, but that's a pretty good advice anyway, thank you, I'll give it a try. If anyone knows better way, please advice.

UPDATE: damn, in Firefox it is almost non-functional :(

Comment: I just made a little search for Firebug. You can install it on Chrome browser too

Comment: Hm, another good advice. I think only Firebug Lite is available that way. Thank you, I'll install Firebug for Chrome and try it.

Comment: Firebug Lite for Google Chrome doesn't have much features, definitely not as rich as Chrome Developer Tools, unfortunately.