# How to debug '10 $digest iterations reached' error in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging

Normally, the message `Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []` might contain a useful hint, but as you can see it's empty.
Most other answers to similar questions will tell you to look for a method that returns a new object for each call, but that's difficult to find in a large application. I'm not using any `$scope.$watch` calls, so no luck there either.

Can I get angular to tell me, somehow, which part of the HTML remains dirty, so I can narrow down the scope?

Comment: The easiest and quickest way to do this, by experience, is to add `console.log()` statements in your code - inside a function particularly. See the console for logs that appear frequently and you can narrow down the cause of the issue to that function or group of functions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So far, it hasn't gotten me any results unfortunately, nothing gets called more than once.

Comment: Then try looking for functions that are called from the view. See if there a cycle - Function A modifies scope variable B which affects function C, which in turn affect scope variable D which affects function A.